# Connecting to X Server

Tags: c, xorg, xserver

I'm trying to write my own program that connects to a local X server that does not use Xlib or XCB, using the X Window System Protocol documentation. After writing the connection data to the server socket I can't seem to read back the server's reply, as the read function blocks.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
  int sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  struct sockaddr_un serv_addr;
  memset((void*)&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(serv_addr.sun_path, "/tmp/.X11-unix/X0");
  int servlen = 17 + sizeof(serv_addr.sun_family);

  int err = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, servlen);

  printf("%d\n", err);

  struct
  {
    uint8_t en;
    uint8_t pad;
    uint16_t major;
    uint16_t minor;
    uint16_t name_len;
    uint16_t data_len;
    uint16_t pad2;
    uint8_t name[4];
    uint8_t data[4];
  } init;

  init.en = 'l';
  init.major = 11;
  init.minor = 0;
  init.name_len = 0;
  init.data_len = 0;

  err = write(sockfd, init, sizeof(init));

  printf("%d\n", err);

  uint8_t buf[5000];

  int n = read(sockfd, buf, 5000);

  return 0;
}
```

What is missing from my code? The connect and write functions return 0.

Comment: Can you confirm that the server (1) got the data you sent to it, and (2) is responding with the data you expect in return?

Comment: The write function returns 0 so I guess it can be assumed that the server received the data, and the server is not responding at all according to the read function not returning.

Comment: `write` returns the number of bytes written, so a zero return indicates that nothing at all was written. Also, the return type of `write` is `ssize_t` not `int` but that's not your problem.

Comment: Silly error by me, the write function initially returned -1, which is why I might have confused 0 with success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is with your `write`:

```
err = write(sockfd, init, sizeof(init));
```

The second parameter should be `&init`, passing just `init` will, effectively, unroll the structure and the computer will see something like this:

```
err = write(sockfd, init.en, init.pad, ..., sizeof(init));
```

Since `write` only looks at three arguments, it will be using one of the `init` members as the size of the buffer to write and that member is probably zero. The actual byte-level argument stack depends on the compiler and architecture so you can tease that our yourself, the important thing is that you're not feeding `write` what you want to.

Your compiler should have caught this, if it didn't then you need to crank up the warning options as high as they will go.

You'll probably want to build the data you send to the X server byte by byte anyway, that way you can make sure you get the byte order and offsets right. Sending `&init` will get you into trouble with the usual suspects (packing, alignment, and byte order).

Comment: Thank you, I am now getting at least some reponse by passing &init.